# Google Map contain location function with foreach and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map api with contain location function .... i am retrieving latitude longitude from database i am using foreach loop to get result.If marker is within polygon it will stop foreach but problem it is not showing any result. Result come out is from last row query how can i fix it.It is showing me only last row from database .Below is my code

```
<?php
if(!empty($zone)){
foreach($zone as $findzone)
{
 $exploded_data=explode('),',$findzone['zone_latlog']);
  $count=count($exploded_data);
   ?>
   <script>
    var latitude = document.getElementById('latitude').value;
    var longitude = document.getElementById('longitude').value;
    var map;
    var coord1 = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
 function initialize() {
              var map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.714760, 73.083160),
                  zoom: 8,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
              var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
                map: map,
                paths: [
                <?php 
                for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
                    echo "new google.maps.LatLng".$exploded_data[$i]."),";
                }
                ?>
                ]
              });
              var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
              for (var i=0; i<bermudaTriangle.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
                 bounds.extend(bermudaTriangle.getPath().getAt(i));
              }
              bounds.extend(coord1);
              var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: coord1
              });
              map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
              map.setZoom(11);
              checkInPolygon(marker1, bermudaTriangle);
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

            function checkInPolygon(marker, polygon) {
              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
              var html = "";
              if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(marker.getPosition(), polygon)) {
                html = "inside polygon";

              } else {
                html = "outside polygon";
              }
              infowindow.setContent(html);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);

            }


                </script>
            <?php 
            }}?>
```

How to fix that problem that show me only only that polygon that has my latitude longitude marker

Comment: looks like the `initialize()` function and the other code is being written inside the loop - why? It might be useful to see some of the raw PHP data that you are using

Comment: To get all result from database thats why i use foreach

Comment: OK but why generate the same javascript code  and functions numerous times? Use PHP to generate a data structure that you can use in javascript and then declare the js functions once and then process the data

Comment: can you add the contents of the php variable `$zone` to the question?